# Feign/Ribbon/Eureka - a RestClient backed by an Apache HttpClient pool is created but never used

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-feign

We are using Feign on top of Ribbon and Eureka.

We noticed a `com.netflix.niws.client.http.RestClient` instance is automatically created for each Feign client but never used. Instead, the `Feign.Builder` creates a `feign.ribbon.RibbonClient` that delegates the actual HTTP call to a `feign.Client.Default` instance. The latter uses standard Java HttpConnection without any pooling feature.

Unfortunately, the creation of these apparently useless `RestClient` instances (one per feign client) comes with its own Apache HttpClient, its own connection pool, housekeeping thread and metrics stuff...

A quick look at the /metrics actuator endpoint shows metrics like:

```
counter.servo.<client name>_createnew: 0
counter.servo.<client name>_delete: 0
counter.servo.<client name>_release: 0
counter.servo.<client name>_request: 0
counter.servo.<client name>_reuse: 0
```

Those metrics are created by `com.netflix.http4.NamedConnectionPool`. Their value stay at 0 whatever the activity.

Did someone experienced the same behaviour?
Why are these `RestClient` instances created for each feign client and never used?

Comment: However, I noticed the `RestClient` is being used if I use a Spring `RestTemplate` to call the remote service instead of a Feign client. Is it possible the RestClient is always created by the Ribbon configuration, even if not used by any other component like when Feign is being used?

Comment: This seems because of the `SpringLBClientFactory` making use of ribbon's `SpringClientFactory`. The latter creates a `RestClient` even if not required by any other bean. May be that factory method should be marked `@Lazy`?

Comment: Maybe you should open an issue in github about this (seems like it should go away)?

Comment: Issue created in github: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/312

Answer (score 0):

Observed behaviour was caused by issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/312.
Fix is scheduled to be included in Spring Cloud 1.0.2